# in this jenkins declarative pipeline, how can I pass a value to DIABLE_AUTH from a file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried load(/path/to/file), but it is giving me an error(unexpected char '\')

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to but this is just a groovy DSL. You've got access to any groove IO operations that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [readFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace) step which is available.

This step parses you a file in the workspace into a String.
You can read DISABLE_AUTH then from this string and use it in the pipeline script.

Here is an example script.

```
def content = readFile 'gradle.properties'

Properties properties = new Properties()
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
properties.load(is)

def runtimeString = 'DIABLE_AUTH'
echo properties."$runtimeString"
DIABLE_AUTH= properties."$runtimeString"
echo DIABLE_AUTH
```